# Appending element to the list in a hashmap

Tags: zig

In the code below when I retrieve the list from hashMap, it is like items in the list get overridden.

```
fn projectStructure() !void {
    var arena = std.heap.ArenaAllocator.init(std.heap.page_allocator);
    defer arena.deinit();
 
    const allocator = arena.allocator();
 
 
    var map = std.StringHashMap(std.ArrayList([]const u8)).init(allocator);
    defer map.deinit();
 
    //var list = std.ArrayList([]const u8).init(allocator);                                                                                                                                                     
    //defer list.deinit();                                                                                                                                                                                     
 
    //try list.append("aaa");                                                                                                                                                                                  
    //try map.put("ss",list);                                                                                                                                                                                  
    // for (map.get("ss").?.items) |item|{                                                                                                                                                                     
    //      std.debug.print("{?s}\n", .{item});                                                                                                                                                                 
    // }                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 
    //std.debug.print("{}\n",.{allocator.detectLeaks()});                                                                                                                                                       
 
    var dir = try std.fs.cwd().openIterableDir(".", .{});
    defer dir.close();
 
    var walker = try dir.walk(allocator);
 
    while(try walker.next()) |item|{
        if(isValidPath(item.path)){
            if(item.kind == std.fs.IterableDir.Entry.Kind.directory){
                // we need to check if the directory is in the dictionary already                                                                                                                               
                if (map.get(item.path) == null ){
                    // we need to add it the project structure                                                                                                                                                  
                    var list = std.ArrayList([]const u8).init(allocator);
                    try map.put(item.path, list);
                    std.debug.print("new directory: {s}\n",.{item.path});
                }
                continue;
                //std.debug.print("directory: {s}\n",.{item.path});                                                                                                                                             
            }
            if (item.kind == std.fs.IterableDir.Entry.Kind.file){
                const filePath = try removeFileFromPath(item.path,item.basename);
                if (map.getPtr(filePath)) |fileList|{
                    std.debug.print("new file added {s} to directory: {s}\n",.{item.basename,filePath});
                    //printDirectoryFiles(filePath,map);                                                                                                                                                        
                    try fileList.append(item.basename);
                    printDirectoryFiles(filePath,map);
                }
                // std.debug.print("file: {s}\n",.{filePath});                                                                                                                                                   
            }
            //std.debug.print("{s}\n",.{item.path});                                                                                                                                                            
        }
    }
}
```

this is the output of the code as can be seen types.zig override the previous main.zig
and append again ( types.zi (this was main.zig before) and types.zig)

```
new directory: Rest
new file added Rest.zig to directory: Rest
file: Rest.zig
new directory: Rest/API
new file added main.zig to directory: Rest/API
file: main.zig
new file added types.zig to directory: Rest/API
file: types.zi
file: types.zig
new directory: Rest/API/Tests
new file added types.zig to directory: Rest/API/Tests
file: types.zig
types.zig
API/Test
Tests/ty
Tests/typ
```

I feel there is something wrong when I append a new element to the list, but I am not sure what could be the fix.

update 1:

I print the address of each list it's like when I add new list to the hashMap it is always the same list

```
new directory: Rest
new list address: array_list.ArrayListAligned([]const u8,null)@7ffebe2b9830
new file added Rest.zig to directory: Rest
list address: *array_list.ArrayListAligned([]const u8,null)@7ffebe2b98c8
file: Rest.zig
new directory: Rest/API
new list address: array_list.ArrayListAligned([]const u8,null)@7ffebe2b9830
new file added main.zig to directory: Rest/API
list address: *array_list.ArrayListAligned([]const u8,null)@7ffebe2b98c8
file: main.zig
new file added types.zig to directory: Rest/API
list address: *array_list.ArrayListAligned([]const u8,null)@7ffebe2b98c8
file: types.zi
file: types.zig
new directory: Rest/API/Tests
new list address: array_list.ArrayListAligned([]const u8,null)@7ffebe2b9830
new file added types.zig to directory: Rest/API/Tests
list address: *array_list.ArrayListAligned([]const u8,null)@7ffebe2b98c8
file: types.zig
types.zig
API/Test
Tests/ty
Tests/typ
```

Comment: What's the implementation of `removeFileFromPath`?

Comment: I don't understand what's going on in the log. How can you have `filePath` be equal to `Rest` (judging by  `new file added Rest.zig to directory: Rest`), but then it's immediately equal to `Rest.zig`?

Comment: file structure in the project is look like this 

Rest/Rest.zig
Rest/API/main.zig
Rest/API/types.zig
Rest/API/Tests/types.zig

Comment: anyway when I check the code when I create new array list it has the same address each time

Comment: How are you printing the address?

Comment: std.debug.print("new list address: {*}\n",.{&list});

Comment: You're simply printing the address of a local variable. Anyway, you're making the same mistake as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74532596/944911) question.

Comment: thanks, I fixed it by adding try fileList.append(try std.mem.Allocator.dupe(allocator, u8, item.basename)); but my question is why item.basename was not live long enough ? and is there more efficient way to do this ?

Comment: Note that you're probably leaking memory this way.

Why would `item.basename` live longer? You need to learn more about how memory, pointers, etc. work. Try reading the section on [memory](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#Memory) in the Zig language reference.

You need to know what you're doing before you can make it more efficient.